# PHP header , csv downloadable error in generating output (unknown new lines character is appending with output), zend

Tags: php, csv, header, zend-framework

Using following code user downloads information (in csv format) from database. But while getting output lots of rows are blank , i.e. in my csv there will be two rows. But while getting csv after first row 2 blank rows will be printed.

```
public generatecsvAction()
{
  $answermodel=new Model_DbTable_Answers();
  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
  //header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8'); // tried this too but still same output
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exportevent.csv");  
  header("Pragma: no-cache");  
  header("Expires: 0");  
  echo "First_Name,Last_Name,Roll_No1,User_name,col1,col2,col3..... \n"; // checked without this \n 
  foreach($testarray as $i) 
  {
    $ans = $answermodel->getanswers1($a,$i);
    if(count($ans)==10) // if user answered all the qustions ,
    {
      //echo "1,";
      foreach($ans as $value)
      {   
        $res=$answermsamodel->findansweroption($value);
        $res=$res.",";
        $s=$s.$res;
      }
      echo $s;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For best practice in Zend, all of the output should be done from the view, not the controller.  Output in your controller will show up after any view content, which may contain blank spaces or other content etc.

Comment: You really shouldnt use the header functions from within a controller, you should use the response object or set up a context.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `$answermsamodel->findansweroption($value)` returns a value with line breaks in it.

Comment: haminsh , as you said its found that after data access request from controller to model line breaks are appending , echoing "abc" before the accessing data using model will print correctley . but after data access using  $answermsamodel->findansweroption($value) will append a line break(but this function return only a value , like a,b etc). any idea about this,

Comment: alternative solutions , as the string 's' does not contains any line breaks , may print it in another action